# mod_rewrite one domain to another while preserving URL for bilingual site

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have two domains: myenglishdomain.com and myfrenchdomain.com. They both point to the same folder on my server (the english domain). The way I've structured the server is that the english content is at myenglishdomain.com/en and my french content is at myenglishdomain.com/fr (note: my english domain, not the french one).

when a user types in myfrenchdomain.com/content I'd like the URL to still read myfrenchdomain.com/content, and yet point to myenglishdomain.com/fr/content

is this possible? What would be the rule(s) to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myfrenchdomain.com
RewriteRule ^/content/(.*) http://myenglishdomain.com/fr/content/$1 [P]
```

Comment: So THAT's what the [proxy] flag is for!